# 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully' while debugging unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have desctructor in my class and I'm starting cmd process on destructor. I got this exception when I was debugging unit test. My class :

```
class Class1
{
    ~Class1()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

My unit test:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    }
```

Also there is no exception when I'm running project in debug mode. How to fix this issue? Did anyone have issue like this?

Comment: Pretty hard to get help with a "nothing went wrong" exception.  But realistically, you'll have to re-think this test.  That "runas" verb is just not very compatible with unit tests, there isn't anybody around to say OK at the UAC prompt.

Comment: @HansPassant, I removed Verb = "runas", but it still throws this exception

Comment: @DIlshod is it possible to post unit test code and unit testing framework you are using ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I could reproduce it. Look, I updated codes

Comment: Problem fixed when I got Process.Start() in new Task. But I still don't understand WHY?

Comment: Hello, could you please share whole code that is neccessary to recreate issue?
`MyEventSource.Log.AppStarted`
`MyEventSource.Log.AppStopped`
Are your internal objects. :)

Comment: @LukaszBalazy I added MyEventSource class

Comment: I would guess the event methods get called on a different context then your test runner, which possibly is not running with your identity. Could very well be that the thread that is writing the events doesn't have rights to execute a process. Check the context in the event writers, appdomain, thread id, etc...

Comment: Also, try `EventSourceSettings.ThrowOnEventWriteErrors`

Comment: @TamirDaniely This exception throws when I start cmd process in desctructor of class. I update codes

Comment: This is definitely not code to put in the finalizer for many reasons. use the `IDispose` pattern instead and call the `Dispose` method where appropriate or use a `using` statement. The key point about finalizers in c# is don't use them as an end-of-lifetime event for an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `try catch` block around the test.

```
[TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1()
  {
     try
     {
         Class1 class1 = new Class1();
         class1 = null;
         // force Garbage Collection for finalizer to run
         GC.Collect();
     }

     catch(Win32Exception w) 
     {
         Console.WriteLine(w.Message);
         Console.WriteLine(w.ErrorCode.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine(w.NativeErrorCode.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine(w.StackTrace);
         Console.WriteLine(w.Source);
         Exception e=w.GetBaseException();
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
  }
```

This will give you the exact error message produced.

---

This could be something as simple as the path not being set. If that is the case. The returned error would be `file not found`.  In that case this would be solved by changing `"cmd.exe"` to `@"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"`

Comment: It's not working. Destuctor isn't woring in 'try' condition. And also in 'catch' it's showing also this exception